# Dynamic Folder per customer

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I've a problem I don't know the solution.
I want when a user click a button (which i have design) it will call the controller method. In this method

1. I want to create a folder if it doesn't exist already in my view directory.
2. Copy a file into that new created directory which is a blade file.
3. Return that blade file with some data.
   I've tried some methods but it doesn't work.
   I'm unable to create the file inside the view and then copy the blade file into it.

Comment: Sounds interesting but we will need some more details. 1) What have you tried so far? 2) Why do you need to create a new blade template per user? (it may be that there is a neater solution!)

Comment: @Spholt first i've run `php artisan storage:link` which has created a syslink in public folder. then in the controller I've `File::makeDirectory('path/filename')` then I've copied the file with `File::copy('from path', 'to path')` But all that goes into the storage syslink directory i cannot create a directory in view directory. And the purpose is that We create custom website for each user. so all the files will be in this directory.

Comment: No one to Answer my question???

Comment: Be patient, some of us need to do our own work. At the end of the day, this is not a paid service :P

Comment: @Spholt I know but i got stuck very badly.